# SiteMapPath doesnt' show Web.sitemap siteMapNode with querystring in url

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have the following web.sitemap portion:

```
<siteMapNode title="MENU" url="">
<siteMapNode url="~/page1.aspx?id=0" title="MENU 1" />
<siteMapNode url="~/page2.aspx" title="MENU 2" />
</siteMapNode>
```

When I am in http://localhost/page1.aspx I cannot see the map path because in my sitemap I have quesrystring ?id=0.
Can I fix it?

Thank you soo much!

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

Now that there is a possibility to be in page1.aspx without any querystring so add it to your sitemap otherwise if there is not a way of use without querystrings. so what are you doing in page1.aspx alone? just don't let users to navigate to page1.aspx alone.

Answer (score 0):

you want to display specific value in navigation bar so you cannot do that with that way you have more ways 
1-use site map provider 
2-make data source which retrieve data from stored procedure or method

I will send you example soon.
best regards

Comment: Hi, it's been almost 8 years.  What's your timeframe on this?  Soon?  Thanks